# Feature disappears after moving it a few times in Vector layer

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to move a point by changing its location every few seconds and redrawing the vector layer.
This works for a few times, but then the dot disappears - it's not off the map (it's only going around a few blocks) and even the getVisibility() and onScreen() return true - it just doesn't show on screen.

I even added zIndex:9999 to the StyleMap, but that didn't change the behaviour.

I have a feature_point variable (OpenLayers.Geometry.Point) and this is how I change it's place (position comes from an array of coordinates)

```
feature_point.geometry.x = position.lon;
feature_point.geometry.y = position.lat;
vector_layer.redraw();
```

Why does it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use native `move` method [OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.move](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.move)

**UPD**

Or use `drawFeature` method instead `redraw();`

```
feature_point.geometry.x = position.lon;
feature_point.geometry.y = position.lat;
vector_layer.drawFeature(feature_point);
```

Comment: umh, but that needs distance as argument? I have a series of locations (coordinates) - I wouldn't want to calculate the distance between them.

Comment: Im update answer. Use `drawFeature` method instead `redraw`, it will redraw only a specific feature

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make a difference. It seems to work exactly like with original method - which makes sense, since this dot is the only feature on the vector layer.